# Failed to extract imported API information for this application in Windows Store app submission

Tags: windows-store-apps, electron-builder, windows-store, appx, appxmanifest

I am trying to publish an appx on the Windows Store built with `electron-builder`.

In the repport, I get this error: `Failed to extract imported API information for this application`

[image]

I have no idea about what this is supposed to mean and I found no documentation about it. I contacted Microsoft Developer Support that just sent me here.

I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fa2b91ea-e8aa-4268-a47d-d2597fd7041f/certification-faile-failed-to-extract-imported-api-information-for-this-application?forum=windowsstore) that mention the issue.

> After two days of trail and error we nailed it. It looks like it has
> something to do with the lenght of filepaths to contents inside the
> app package.

Notice the difference between the cause and the error message. This probably means that this error is just a random generic error that is raised when something happens, and doesn't provide any meaningful information about what exactly went wrong...

The issue is that now, I have absolutely no idea about how to move forward. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the WACK tool developed by Microsoft to test the packages sent to the store is crashing if any file complete path is longer than 255 characters, and it returns that random error giving you the impression that you did something wrong on the manifest.

The best you can do for now is to measure the full path of all the files that are going to be packaged into your app and try to rename the longest ones, or try to reach the Microsoft support. It's 300$ / request, but you can get it refunded as it's clearly their own responsibility.